# iOS, PWA, Azure AD Authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, progressive-web-apps

I have been building a PWA for a company that I'm currently doing my internship at. Everything has been running smoothly on both devices (Android/iOS) except for the notifications part. But never mind.

Since the release of iOS 11.3, and Safari 11.1 my PWA kind of breaks at login, I'm using Azure Active Directory to authenticate all the users, so when they open the app they get redirected to the login page. Which opens in Safari, and stays in Safari after login, making the PWA useless.

This is how I initialize the login

```
const config: adal.Config = {
    tenant: '*******',
    clientId: '***************' };

    this.service.init(config);

    this.service.handleWindowCallback();

    if(!this.service.userInfo.autheticated) {
        this.service.login();
    }
}
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/securing-an-angular-application-with-azure-ad/) but used adal-angular5 instead of 4, and now with the current version of iOS (11.3.1), the login process works fine. Note: For multi-factor auth, make sure you choose SMS to mobile (rather than "send notification to my mobile app"), so you can enter the code into the PWA without needing to change to a different app (losing focus reloads the app and restarts the MFA login process). Let me know if this helps, or if you have any other questions - I can check my build. Good luck.

Comment: Update: My above comment was when building a project that was NOT a PWA. The issue you are facing is due to Apple detecting a URL link to an external scope (website) and therefore handing it off to a safari window.